# A falling steel beam - Maximum induced voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, voltage, induction

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain how to answer this question:

> *A 2 m long steel beam is falling from a height of 12,5 m. During the fall, the beam is oriented in an east-west direction. The earth magnetic field is 48 microT and has an inclination of 61 degrees. What is the maximal induced voltage in the beam during the fall?*

$$e = lvB$$

Am I supposed to use the conservation of energy in some way? Am I supposed to use the horisontal component of the earth magnetic field, or the vertical one? How am I sure I have the maximal induced voltage...?

Comment: what equation is e=lvB ? I have come across  F=q(v X B) , force on a charge moving in B and F (IL X B) for a force on current carrying conductor in a B. and i think the maximum induced emf maybe zero(macroscopically) if the beam is not conducting current or has specific charge on it.

Comment: e = lvB is how you calculate the induced voltage on a conductor with the length l which is moving with the velocity v perpendicular to a magnetic field B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that since the steel beam has conduction electrons that are free to move, the movement of the charges in a magnetic field causes a magnetic force to act. The magnetic force causes the electrons to accumulate at one part of the curved surface of the rod, thereby creating a potential difference. The charges keep accumulating till the potential difference can stop further accumulation. And that potential difference is known as the [*Hall potential difference*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect). This potential difference is your "maximum" potential difference.

I won't delve into the math since you only wanted how to approach the problem.

This pdf has more problems on the hall effect from Fundamentals of Physics, HRW: www.phy.olemiss.edu/~cremaldi/PHYS415/Hall_Effect_HW.pdf

Comment: if there is no current in the conductor is the hall effect still observed ?

Comment: @Gowtham Obviously there has to be current so that the charges 'move' to accumulate at a particular surface.

Comment: In the question where is the current produced from ?

Comment: thanks a lot! However, do you mind assisting me with the math as well?

Comment: @Gunnar Well, you can accept the answer as well by clicking on the 'tick' mark beside my answer. Google 'hall effect problems' for sample problems on the same. You'll get an idea as to the method of solving; it's really easy once you do that.

Comment: nevermind i read through some literature there will definitely be an emf !